# Php mysql table column name conflict

Tags: php

Running into an issue here caused by something beyond my control.
I am running a DB query on a table I did not create, it has a table column named "end".  This is screwing up my foreach loop as it only gets the first instance and then stops on that particular variable.

Here is my current code:

```
$eventDates = array();
  foreach( $events as $event ) :
    $eventDates[ $event->post_id ] = $event->start; 
    $eventEnd[ $event->post_id ] = $event->end; 
    $eventVenue[ $event->post_id ] = $event->venue;     
endforeach;
```

The $event->end; is the problem.  Is there another way I can output that data that won't cause a conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try aliasing the column name in the request otherwise.

`select end as thisIsTheEnd` ...

Comment: since i used SELECT * in my query, how do I specify this and still get other columns?

Comment: i used SELECT post_id, end AS finish  and that worked.  Thanks!